# Get Option value by id works in chrome and not mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, mozilla

I want to insert the value of an option selected from max size field in price field. This works in chrome but not in Mozilla. I've been trying to figure out why but no success.

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="id_max_size">Max 
   Size</label><select name="max_size" title="" required class="form-control" id="id_max_size">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Size ↓</option>
   <option value="10">AAA</option>
   <option value="20">BBB</option>
   <option value="30">CCC</option>
   <option value="40">DDD</option>
</select>
```

```
document.getElementById('id_max_size').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('id_price').value = event.target.value  
};;
```

How do I make it work with Mozila? what am I missing?

Comment: Why not using $this instead if event.target?

Comment: I don't really know javascript. You mean I should replace event.target with $this?

Comment: Sorry. My suggestion was using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code to the following and it will work. You can add `change` `EventListener` and passin the `event` as parameter.

```js
document.getElementById('id_max_size').addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    document.getElementById('id_price').value = event.target.value;
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only" for="id_max_size">Max 
  Size</label>

  <select name="max_size" title="" required class="form-control" id="id_max_size">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Size ↓</option>
    <option value="10">AAA</option>
    <option value="20">BBB</option>
    <option value="30">CCC</option>
    <option value="40">DDD</option>
  </select>

  <input id="id_price" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks now working! I have another question that is related to Mozilla too. Can I go ahead and ask?

Comment: I think it would be better to raise another question.